# How to optimize SQL query returning nested JSON?

Tags: sql, postgresql

As my questions indicates I'd like some advice on how to optimize this sql query. Due to its relative slow performance (~10s) when returning lots of results (>~250) some serverless functions time out on my backend.

Tables:

```
word        52.000 rows
sense       70.000 rows
inflection   1.700 rows
```

sql:

```
create table word (id int8, level int2, homonymnumber int2, alpha int8, frequency int8, hangul text, hanja text, pronounciation text, audio text, typeeng text, typekr text)

create table inflection (inflectionid int8, id int8, inflections text, inflectionlinks json)

create table sense (senseid int8, id int8, translation text, definition text, krdefinition text, sensenr int2)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

sql:

```
select json_agg(
        distinct jsonb_build_object(
            'item',
            jsonb_build_object(
                'Id',
                word.id,
                'Alpha',
                word.alpha,
                'Frequency',
                word.frequency,
                'HomonymNumber',
                word.homonymnumber,
                'Pronounciation',
                word.pronounciation,
                'Audio',
                word.audio,
                'TypeKr',
                word.typekr,
                'TypeEng',
                word.typeeng,
                'Hanja',
                word.hanja,
                'Hangul',
                word.hangul,
                'Senses',
                (
                    select json_agg(
                            jsonb_build_object(
                                'Translation',
                                sense.translation,
                                'Definition',
                                sense.definition,
                                'DefinitionKr',
                                sense.definitionkr,
                                'SenseNr',
                                sense.sensenr
                            )
                        )
                    from sense
                    where sense.id = word.id
                ),
                'Inflection',
                inflection.inflections,
                'InflectionLinks',
                inflection.inflectionlinks
            )
        )
    )
from word
    full join inflection on word.id = inflection.id
    right join sense on word.id = sense.id
where word.hangul similar to concat('%', term, '%')
    or sense.translation similar to concat('%', term, '%')
    or inflection.inflections similar to concat('%', term, '%')
```

Comment: Those `similar/like '%something%'` are hard to optimize... Please, add to the question this information: structure of the indexes of the tables and total number of rows for each table

Comment: In fact, if you could create a dbfiddle example, that would be the best option :)

Comment: I looked into full textsearch but that seems quite complicated due to the nature of the Korean language and my inexperience. I'll edit my question and add the information.

Comment: Is "term" here a named parameter?  Column "definitionkr" also does not exist, is that also a parameter or just a misspelling?

Comment: Having conditions on multiple tables ORed together is going to make it very hard to optimize.  You might need to use UNION or UNION ALL over different queries, with pg_trgm indexes.

Comment: Mistake on my side. "definitionkr" is a column on the sense table. What is meant with "ORed"? So I would create one query for every where statement and afterwards use UNION merge the results?

Answer (score 1):

Try row_to_json function on postgresql, same time your query will be simple. Fox example:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    bookcode int4 NULL,
    bookname varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT books_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(3, 1245, 'Book1');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(4, 1655, 'Book5');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(5, 2211, 'Book4');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(6, 1219, 'Book8');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(7, 9955, 'Book2');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(1, 2267, 'Book1');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(2, 12322, 'Book2');
INSERT INTO books (id, bookcode, bookname) VALUES(8, 43543, 'Book10');
```

After:

```
select row_to_json(a) from books a 

Result: 
{"id":3,"bookcode":1245,"bookname":"Book1"}
{"id":4,"bookcode":1655,"bookname":"Book5"}
{"id":5,"bookcode":2211,"bookname":"Book4"}
{"id":6,"bookcode":1219,"bookname":"Book8"}
{"id":7,"bookcode":9955,"bookname":"Book2"}
{"id":1,"bookcode":2267,"bookname":"Book1"}
{"id":2,"bookcode":12322,"bookname":"Book2"}
{"id":8,"bookcode":43543,"bookname":"Book10"}

Or 

select jsonb_build_object('item', jsonb_agg(row_to_json(a))) from books a

Result: 
{
    "item": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "bookcode": 1245,
            "bookname": "Book1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "bookcode": 1655,
            "bookname": "Book5"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "bookcode": 2211,
            "bookname": "Book4"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "bookcode": 1219,
            "bookname": "Book8"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "bookcode": 9955,
            "bookname": "Book2"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "bookcode": 2267,
            "bookname": "Book1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "bookcode": 12322,
            "bookname": "Book2"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "bookcode": 43543,
            "bookname": "Book10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Field names you can change with using aliases.